# Transferring Images from .NET to Delphi

Tags: .net, wcf, delphi

I wonder if anyone can advise.  I have written a .NET 4 WCF service which is intended to serve scanned documents and am struggling to get a Delphi 7 consumer to work.

On the .NET side I am converting Images to Bitmaps and then to Arrays of Byte using the following code :

```
        using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap(fileName))
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            _bytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
        }
```

On the Consumer side I want to read the ByteArray into a TImage.Picture and this is where the plan has foundered.  The following code errors on the 'LoadFromStream' line with

> EInvalidGraphic with message 'Bitmap image is not valid'

```
procedure TBarcodeImageForm.FetchFile;
var
  bytes : TByteDynArray;
  info  : TDocInfo;
  Stream : TMemoryStream;
  bmp : TBitMap;
begin
  info := TDocInfo(FDocList.Items[lbFIles.ItemIndex]);
  bytes := FDocButton.FetchDocument(info.FilePath).Data;
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create();
  try
    Stream.Write(bytes[0], Length(Bytes));
    Stream.Position := 0;
    bmp := TBitMap.Create;
    bmp.LoadFromStream(stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

By using a TFileStream in place of the memory stream above I have demonstrated that the data are valid - that is I can load the result in MSPaint.  I have to admit I am stuck for the next step : Is Delphi 7 too outdated to handle modern bitmaps ?  Is the fact that the files on the server side are tiffs and jpgs relevant?  What should I do next ?

Any advice gratefully received.

UPDATE -------------------

I altered the code so that a JPG was being passed across and the results are very similar.  This time I get JPEG Error #53 when I try and Load the image client-side.  If I use a TFileStream and save to disk the resultant file looks fine with Windows Picture Viewer, but still will not load into the TImage Component.

Client Side now looks like this

```
  stream := TFileStream.Create('c:\temp.jpg', fmCreate);
  try
    Stream.Write(bytes[0], Length(Bytes));
    Stream.Position := 0;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;

  try
    imgDocument.Picture.LoadFromFile('c:\temp.jpg');
  except end;
```

Server-side (publishing the whole data contract this time in case)

```
    [DataContract]
public class ImageData
{
    private byte[] _bytes;

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] Data
    {
        get { return _bytes; }
        set { _bytes = value; }
    }

    public ImageData(string fileName)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Image img = Image.FromFile(fileName))
            {
                img.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            _bytes = new Byte[memStream.Length];
            int i = 0;
            while (i < memStream.Length)
                i += memStream.Read(_bytes, i, 128000);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE -----------------------------------------------------------------

A successful test of the service from a Winforms consumer used the following code.

```
if (docList != null)
{
    using (MemoryStream memStream = 
        new MemoryStream(client.FetchDocument(docList.Items[0].FilePath).Data))
    {
        System.Drawing.Image img = Image.FromStream(memStream); 
        pictureBox1.Image = img; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It always helps to post what the problem actually is.  If code based, then show what you have.  If design based, tell us what you are thinking.

Comment: Sorry about that I committed the question long before I was ready

Comment: It might be related to the fact you're serializing something other than a bitmap (JPEG or TIFF). Delphi's `TBitmap` requires a valid bitmap header. You might try using `TJPegImage.LoadFromStream` and test fetching a JPEG; if that solves the problem, you can probably find a TIFF component for D7 as well; you'd have to read the first few bytes from the array to determine which type of image you were receiving and create the proper graphic to handle it.

Comment: I am not bound to use TBitMap, I just assumed it was the lowest common denominator.  The actual scanned documents might be in a variety of formats.  I will experiment with jpegs and see if they are any more reliable.  Any thoughts on why MSPaint can read the output but TBitMap cannot ?

Comment: @Hugh - Have you verified TImage.Picture *cannot* load bitmap files saved through TFileStream which MSPaint can display?

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz - yes I have.  I have also demonstrated that jpegs are the same

Comment: Does TBitMap.LoadFromStream expect a bitmap or a TBitMap?

Comment: @Ken - I am in control of both sides of the exchange.  I have changed the code now so that a jpg is being passed across and it hasnt helped.  The TJpegImage.LoadFromStream and LoadFromFile also error (#53) but the file on disk is prefectly viewable with Windows Picture Viewer

Comment: I quickly knocked up a WinForms client and this seems to work.  That rules out the service which leaves either marshalling or TImage.  Given that the disk copy of the output is valid for Windows picture viewer, does that mean proof the problem lies with TImage ?

Comment: @Hugh - Probably. It is possible though that the viewers you are testing with are tolerating invalid files. Re-save one of the files with an image program (using the same format, i.e. A8R8G8B8 etc..) that you know that D7's TImage is able to display, then you can probably workout what's wrong with the files by diffing the headers..

Comment: @Sertac - what an excellent suggestion

Comment: I have discovered that the original file - ie the one on the server, will not load into TImage either.  There is no problem with the mashalling at all.  Given that these files are fine in PictureViewer, Paint et al. Even my diff software showed 2 apparently identical images, although the binary contents were quite different.  I noticed an extra '00' at the end of the file.  Is it possible I am supplying 1 too many bytes ?

Comment: @sertac - I am still stuck for an explanation as to why bitMaps and JPegs are BOTH giving me issues, but in any case - can you assist in a method to set the format to, say,  A8R8G8B8 ?

Comment: @Hugh - The software producing the image would set the format, the VCL, while reading the image, proceeds according the information contained in the info header. If you can upload one of your failing bitmaps to some place, I'll try to understand how it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are OK with staying with a Bitmap image, you might want to try reading the image from stream via TJPegImage (out of the JPeg unit).   I'm doing something similar to what you're attempting, but am getting the image bytes direct from a .Net 4 wrapper around a .Net imaging library via AtoZed's "CrossTalk" product.

So first I'm having to convert a .Net MemoryStream object passed across the boundary to a Delphi array of byte.  I then load it into a Delphi TMemoryStream and bring it into the TJpegImage.

(I initially had the same problem that you did until I decided that the LoadfromFile was apparently tailoring how the load was done based on the filename.  Based on that, I explicitly created the proper image variant for JPegs, Tiffs, etc. instead of trying to load it as a generic TImage.)

This works for me with Delphi7 when the image being returned was a Jpeg:

```
  dJpegImage: TJpegImage;
  imageMemoryStream: MemoryStream;
  pictureBoxImageOutput: TImage;
  lengthImageByteArray: Integer;   // already set before this fragment based on the .Net Image info
  imageDelphiByteArray: array of byte;
  ...
  ...
  imageStream := TMemoryStream.Create();
  imageStream.WriteBuffer(imageDelphiByteArray[0], lengthImageByteArray);
  imageStream.Position := 0;
  dJpegImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
  dJpegImage.LoadFromStream(imageStream);
  pictureBoxImageOutput.Picture.Graphic := dJpegImage;
```

Comment: thanks for that - that is pretty much how the client side looks now - it is clearly better to not hit the disk client-side.

Answer (score 1):

I get the impression that you're getting WCF to take care of the process of marshalling and serialising data between the server and the clients (both auto-generated for you by tools?) and that you don't really have much control over the "on-the-wire" format, and now you want to write a client in Delphi 7 that can read this.

I'll warn you that you're in for an uphill struggle, but if your WCF is using SOAP messages then you've got a chance as you should be able to write a SOAP client in Delphi that consumes your WCF service's messages.

As for the images themselves, I don't know how they're serialized. But once you find out it should be easy. Assuming that WCF is not simply serializing a System.Drawing.Bitmap and is instead transferring the raw bytes of a Bitmap file on-disk then you're all set: just dump the WCF message's bytes to disk or an in-memory buffer and open them with TBitmap.

Comment: I have taken very great care to specify the data contract - the 'fetchFile' method returns an array of bytes.  I have all my other methods working sweetly.  On the Delphi side I have relied on wsdlImp to create the interface but I am quite sure that the data received is what is expected - as I said in my post - if I save the received stream to a file it is a perfectly good graphic.

Comment: Your third paragraph pretty much sums up my problem - it should be straighforward, but it aint working.  Yes I am using SOAP.

Comment: The problem isn't bitmap support in Delphi, it's a WCF-to-Delphi-SOAP-RTL impedance mismatch. Delphi's SOAP RTL can't seamlessly handle ALL possible WCF API signatures (you call them data contracts). How I wish it could.

Comment: @Warren - I have managed to resolve the WCF-to-Delphi issues.  I found that by being very explicit in the Data contract, plus installing the Soap patches from Embarcadero, WSDLImp had no problem creating a good interface.  I can see that had the service not been under my control then it would have been a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, everyone - this turned out to be a red-herring.  The issue was that the images I was serving were not valid in the first place.  A quick 'phone call to a third-party vendor was all that was necessary.

On the plus-side, it means the code samples I provided are basically sound.